# Explicit Calculation of the Euler class for the 2-Sphere using transition functions

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I have been trying to learn about characteristic classes for months now, and every time I try a simple example something goes wrong. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to follow the procedure found in [Bott & Tu] in which the Euler class of an oriented, rank 2 bundle is constructed from the bundle transition maps. Here is what I have done so far:

Consider the two-sphere $S^2$ with the standard embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as covered by two coordinate patches $U_1$ and $U_2$ which miss out the north and south poles respectively. And take $$\sigma_1 \colon U_1 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \quad ; \quad (x,y,z) \mapsto \frac{1}{1-z}(x,y)$$   $$\sigma_2 \colon U_2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \quad ; \quad (x,y,z) \mapsto \frac{1}{1+z}(x,y)$$ as stereographic projection maps giving coordinate charts.

Then the tangent bundle of $S^2$ on the overlap $U_1 \cap U_2$ (which is everywhere except the two poles) should inherit two frames, given by $\{D_1(\sigma_1^{-1}),D_2(\sigma_1^{-1})\} $ and $ \{D_1(\sigma_2^{-1}),D_2(\sigma_2^{-1})\} $.

Now next what I have said is that, in order to find the bundle transition function which assigns to each point of $U_1 \cap U_2$ the transformation between these frames, it suffices by functoriality of the operator $D$ to find the push-forward of the coordinate transition map $\sigma_2 \circ \sigma_1^{-1} \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which I have calculated acts like $\sigma_2 \circ \sigma_1^{-1} \colon (a, b) \mapsto \frac{1}{a^2+b^2}(a,b) $

Then from this you can calculate $D(\sigma_2 \circ \sigma_1^{-1}) \colon (a,b) \mapsto  
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{-a^2 + b^2}{(a^2 + b^2)^2} & \frac{-2ab}{(a^2+b^2)^2} \\
   \frac{-2ab}{(a^2+b^2)^2} & \frac{a^2 - b^2}{(a^2 + b^2)^2} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ and I think this gives bundle transition function for the tangent bundle of the sphere in my case.

The problem is that I don't understand how from here you are supposed to reduce the structure group from $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ to $U(1)$, and hence obtain a real valued function assigning a rotation to each point in the overlap. How do I obtain a value, at each point $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, for the "rotation" of the above matrix?

Comment: It might be easier to work with complex charts, thinking of the sphere as $\Bbb CP^1$. Then you should get transition functions $1/z^2$ (depending on which way we're going). Does this make it a bit clearer to you if you restrict to $|z|=1$ in the overlap of the charts?

Comment: Thanks Ted, working with complex charts does make the calculation much simpler, thanks! But it has only opened up a new kettle of fish for me. 
If I take the same cover, given by $U_1=\{[z_1,z_2] : z_1 \neq 0\}$, $U_2=\{[z_1,z_2] : z_2 \neq 0\}$, with coordinates $\sigma_1 : [z_1, z_2] \mapsto z_2/z_1$, $\sigma_2 : [z_1, z_2] \mapsto z_1/z_2$, then the coordinate-transition functions are equal and inverses of each other, $\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2^{-1} = \sigma_2 \circ \sigma_1^{-1} : \mathbb{C}-\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$;$z \mapsto 1/z$

Comment: But then by the inverse function theorem, this would imply that the induced tangent bundle-transition functions are also equal and inverses of each other. Therefore at every point in the overlap $U_1 \cap U_1$ one moves from the respective tangent bundles induced by the two coordinate systems by equal and inverse rotations. i.e. a rotation by $\pi$.

But then this would imply that the euler class of the sphere is zero, which I know is definitely not right!

Do you know where I am going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be cancelling somehow. There is a rotation by $2\cdot 2\pi$ (the degree of the map $z\mapsto z^2$ is $2$). The fact that for $f(z)=1/z$ we have $f=f^{-1}$ is definitely leading you astray. Concretely, $z=1/w$, so $\partial/\partial z = -w^2\partial/\partial w$ and vice-versa. That doesn't make transition functions trivial :)

Comment: Ah thanks, sorry but I have still spent all morning and yesterday struggling with this. So at a point $p$ on the sphere, we have $\sigma_1(p)=re^{i\theta}$ and the transition from a tangent frame induced by $\sigma_1$ at $p$ to a tangent frame induced by $\sigma_2$ at $p$ is given by a rotation of $-2\theta$, using the formula you showed me above. 
Then I get $\phi_{12}:U_1 \cap U_2 \to \mathbb{R}$; $p \mapsto -2\theta$. But then how to I find the Euler class from here? I would have thought a partition of unity $\{ \rho_1, \rho_2 \}$ subordinate to my cover could just be {(1/2),(1/2)}. But

Comment: but then by the defining formula for the Euler class, I should get $e(S^2)=(1/2\pi)\sum_{\gamma=1}^2\mathrm{d}(\rho_\gamma\mathrm{d}\phi_{1\gamma})=0$!

Also it seems geometrically incorrect that the rotations between the frames should be a function of $\theta$. I would have thought that the difference in the tangent frames would grow corresponding to the radial component as the stereographic projections distort more...

Thanks so much for helping sorry I'm being so slow with it all!

Comment: This is getting to be a long conversation :) You definitely have a misconception about partitions of unity. Remember they have to be compactly supported in the respective open sets. You can sort of fake it on $\Bbb CP^1$ by using $\rho_0 = 1/(1+|z|^2)$ and $\rho_1=|z|^2/(1+|z|^2)$. These die outside the sets even though they aren't compactly supported. You're trying to follow p. 73 of Bott/Tu? (My edition has typos, with the $d$ missing in $d\log g_{\alpha\beta}$.) Remember that $g(x) = e^{i\theta(x)}$ here.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, with my partition of unity the euler class would always basically be zero. But since the open covers each cover everywhere but a single point, does this mean you can choose a partition of unity which takes the value 1/2 evrywhere except for in some small neighbourhood of the poles, and so the Euler class can be localised to an arbitrary neighbourhood of the poles?
Using your partition of unity, we get the Euler class by $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \mathrm{d} (\frac{1}{1+|z|^2}\mathrm{d}(\log (e^{i\theta}))$$

Comment: which equals $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \mathrm{d} (\frac{1}{1+|z|^2}\mathrm{d}(-i \log(\frac{z}{|z|}))$$
how does this make sense though when $|z|$ isn't holomorphic?

Yeah I know this is now quite a conversation, thanks for clearing my head of so many contradictions!

Comment: As you know, $df$ makes sense for any smooth (or $C^1$) function. The point is that when $f$ is holomorphic, we have $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz = f'(z)dz$, with no $d\bar z$ term. In this case, $f(z)=\log(e^{i\theta})$ is pure imaginary, and so $df$ will likewise be pure imaginary. That is, the coefficient of $d\bar z$ will the negative of the conjugate of the coefficient of $dz$.

Comment: Thanks Ted, great news I got the calculation to work finally! Taking the above formula in polar coordinates one has $\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathrm{d}(\frac{1}{1+r^2}\mathrm{d}(-2\theta))$ which equals $\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^2}\mathrm{d}r\wedge \mathrm{d}\theta$ which integrating over the entire plane gives.... 2!! Thanks so much for your consistent prodding.